# Counting rows in MySQL (highscore)

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a game with a highscore table in MySQL.

I have a "My scores" button that needs to retrieve the users scores, e.g.:

```
10. John  395

42. John  340

90. John  10
```

How should I go out retrieving the rank (10th, 42th, 90th) of each score of the user?
I could pull all the scores from the database and iterate through them but that doesn't seem like a good solution.

Let me try to expand:
I retrieve all MY scores from the database. E.g. 10 scores. I want to display these 10 scores however I won't know what the rank of these scores is compared to the other scores in my database! (10th, 16th, etc) ..Hope that makes more sense...

Thanks

Comment: What is the structure of your table? What have you tried so  far? What is the price of tea in China?

Comment: Look up the MySQL keywords ORDER BY and LIMIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the position in the total list you either need to build up a list every time you want this overview, or use a stored procedure to build a list for a given moment. You could 'cache' a list on a given interval. Or maybe update a list when some one played a game that would change the top 100.

As @WhiteElephant suggested, you'd be making the table every time you want the data.
@stefandoorn suggest to not use the optimized count of sql, i think this is not efficient enough for these kind of computations.

Answer (score 1):

A simple SQL query would do it for you. For example, if you want the 10th score, you could use:

```
SELECT name, score FROM highscores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 9
```

The offset will always be the position required - 1.

If you want to have the associated rank as a column beside the score, you could do the following:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 position, name, score FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, highscores ORDER BY score DESC
```

This doesn't work with an offset (the position number will always start at 1). The result would be something like the following:

```
+----------+-------------+-------+
| position | name        | score |
+----------+-------------+-------+
|        1 | Player 1    | 27681 |
|        2 | Player 2    | 14982 |
+----------+-------------+-------+
```

But I think the best solution is to just loop through the returned values with an index and use the index to keep track of the position.

Comment: The problem isn't retrieving the data, I can retrieve it but once I have done so I don't know what rank belongs to which score!

Comment: Let me try to expand:
I retrieve all MY scores from the database. E.g. 10 scores. I want to display these 10 scores however I won't know what the rank of these scores is compared to the other scores in my database! (10th, 16th, etc) ..Hope that makes more sense...

Comment: If you want rank, take a look at http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/how-to-get-rank-using-mysql-query/

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  id, name, score,(select count(*) FROM highscores AS higherscores WHERE higherscores.score>currentscores.score)+1 AS rank
FROM
  highscores AS currentscores
WHERE name="john"
;
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding explicitly ranking every score and then sifting through that. It's worth noting that records may "tie" for 2nd place, for instance. (Also, this could equivalently be expressed in a JOIN construct.)

Answer (score -1):

Just use `ORDER BY`score`DESC` in the end of your query to sort them in reversed order (from high to low). When iterating and showing it in PHP you can use a count:

Query e.g.: `SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC`

```
$count = 1;
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC';
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo $count . ' ' . $fetch->score . '<br />';
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: This is what he said he didn't want to do